# Copying data from multiple pdf files

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have pdf files from which I would like to copy all the data to a column in a spreadsheet.

Here is the code I have. All it does is open the pdf, use control-a, then control-c to copy then activates the workbook, finds an open column and pastes the data with a control-v Sendkey.

I have a range with path names it opens and copies data from all but only pastes the last one.

```
Sub StartAdobe1()

Dim AdobeApp As String
Dim AdobeFile As String
Dim StartAdobe
Dim fname As Variant
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim Filename As String

For Each fname In Range("path")

    AdobeApp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
    StartAdobe = Shell("" & AdobeApp & " " & fname & "", 1)

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    SendKeys "^a", True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    SendKeys "^c"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    SendKeys ("%{F4}")
    Windows("transfer (Autosaved).xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("new").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select

    SendKeys "^v"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")

Next fname
```

Comment: Do you have Acrobat (not the Reader)  installed on your computer. If so, you can use the Acrobat object model to copy the data from PDF into Excel, without using `SendKeys`. Let me know if you do, I will post an answer with sample code

Comment: yes i have acrobat as well

Answer (score 2):

Jeanno's right, if you have Acrobat then using its API library to work with the file directly is much better than the workarounds. I use this every day to convert pdf files into database entries.

Your code has a few problems, but I suspect the biggest issue is the use of `SendKeys "^v"` to paste into Excel. You're better off selecting the cell you want then using `Selection.Paste`. Or even better, transfer the contents of the clipboard to a variable, then parse it out as needed on the backend before writing to your spreadsheet--but that adds a bunch of complexity and doesn't help you a lot in this case.

To use the code below, be sure to select your 'Acrobat x.x Type Library' under Tools>References.

```
Sub StartAdobe1()
    Dim fName       As Variant
    Dim wbTransfer  As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wsNew       As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim dOpenCol    As Double
    Dim oPDFApp     As AcroApp
    Dim oAVDoc      As AcroAVDoc
    Dim oPDDoc      As AcroPDDoc

    'Define your spreadsheet
    Set wbTransfer = Workbooks("transfer (Autosaved).xlsm")
    Set wsNew = wbTransfer.Sheets("new")
    'Find first open column
    dOpenCol = ws.Cells(1, columns.count).End(xlToleft).Column + 1

    'Instantiate Acrobat Objects
    Set oPDFApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set oAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    Set oPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

For Each fName In Range("path")

    'Open the PDF file. The AcroAVDoc.Open function returns a true/false 
    'to tell you if it worked
    If oAVDoc.Open(fName.Text, "") = True Then
        Set oPDDoc = oAVDoc.GetPDDoc
    Else
        Debug.Assert False
    End If

    'Copy all using Acrobat menu
    oPDFApp.MenuItemExecute ("SelectAll")
    oPDFApp.MenuItemExecute ("Copy")

    'Paste into open column
    wbTransfer.Activate
    wsNew.Cells(1, dOpenCol).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Select next open column
    dOpenCol = dOpenCol + 1

    oAVDoc.Close (1)    '(1)=Do not save changes
    oPDDoc.Close

Next

    'Clean up
    Set wbTransfer = Nothing
    Set wsNew = Nothing
    Set oPDFApp = Nothing
    Set oAVDoc = Nothing
    Set oPDDoc = Nothing


End Sub
```

Note: 
1-There is also a menu item `oPDFApp.MenuItemExecute ("CopyFileToClipboard")` that should do the select all and copy in one step, but I have had problems with it so I stick to the two-step method above.

2-A pdf file consists of two objects, the `oAVDoc` and the `oPDDoc`. Different aspects of the file are controlled by each. In this case you might only need the `oAVDoc`. Try commenting out the lines dealing with `oPDDoc` and see if it works without them.

Comment: I know this is old, but your "Find first open column" references ws not wsNew :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite get your code to work, but my guess is that it's copying all of the data, but overwriting it each time through the loop.  To fix this try:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1).Select
```

instead of the two lines that begin activesheet.range("A1").Select and Selection.End....

Comment: thank you. it just gave me the same result. I'll give you an example. Right now i have the range for just 2 file paths (for simplicity while i work out the bugs). It opens the first pdf i can see that it copies all the data (control-a) then the spreadsheet is activated and the right cell is selected. However it does not paste it just goes on to open the next pdf where all its data is selected, spreadsheet activated again and cell selected again, but this time it does paste the data.

Comment: It may be worth trying more files to see if it only copies the second one, the last one, skips the first one, or some other combination of files.

Answer (score 0):

try this code this might work:

```
 Sub Shell_Copy_Paste()

   Dim o As Variant
   Dim wkSheet As Worksheet

   Set wkSheet = ActiveSheet

   o = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe C:\Users\saurabh.ad.sharma\Desktop\red.pdf", vbNormalFocus)

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)) 'Wait for Acrobat to load

   SendKeys "^a"   'Select All
   SendKeys "^c"   'Copy
   SendKeys "%{F4}"    'Close shell application

   wkSheet.Range("B5").Select
   SendKeys "^v"   'Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

BELOW CODE WILL COPY DATA FROM PDF & will PASTE IT IN WORD THEN COPY DATA FROM WORD AND THEN PASTE IT TO THE EXCEL .

NOW Why I am copying data from pdf to word  & then copying from word and pasting it to the excel because i want the data from the pdf in exact format to my excel sheet if i copy directly from pdf to excel it will paste the whole data from pdf into a single cell means even if i am having two columns or multiple rows it will paste all of my data into one column and that too in single cell but if i copy from word to excel it will retain its original format and two columns will get pasted as two columns only in excel.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()  '(load pdf)


   Dim o As Variant
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 o = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe C:\Users\saurabh.ad.sharma\Desktop\Book1.pdf", vbNormalFocus)   'loading adobe reader & pdf file from their location
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))
   SendKeys ("^a")
SendKeys ("^c")
 SendKeys "%{F4}"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
 Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 appWord.Visible = True
 appWord.Documents.Add.Content.Paste
With appWord

       .ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\pdf" & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdocument   'saving word file in docx format
        .ActiveWindow.Close
        .Quit
    End With

MsgBox " pdf is loaded "
MsgBox " Paste to EXCEL "

    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
     appWord.Visible = True

  appWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\saurabh.ad.sharma\Desktop\pdf.docx" 'opening word document
      appWord.Selection.WholeStory
      appWord.Selection.Copy
   Set wkSheet = ActiveSheet
    wkSheet.Range("A1").Select
    wkSheet.Paste 'pasting to the excel file

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the more modified version of my above code it will not save any document it will save data in clipboard and will do the execution fast..

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()  '(load pdf)


   Dim o As Variant
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 o = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe C:\Users\saurabh.ad.sharma\Desktop\Book1.pdf2", vbNormalFocus)
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2))
   SendKeys ("^a")
SendKeys ("^c")
 SendKeys "%{F4}"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
 Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 appWord.Visible = False
 appWord.Documents.Add.Content.Paste
With appWord

       .Selection.WholeStory
       .Selection.Copy
       .ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
       .Quit
End With

MsgBox " pdf is loaded "
MsgBox " Paste to EXCEL "


   Set wkSheet = ActiveSheet
    wkSheet.Range("A1").Select
    wkSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The best solution is, as it was mentioned before, to use Adobe API. In my case it was impossible because macro was intended for 100+ users without Adobe Pro on their PC.

Ultimate solution that I have developed recently was to build converted in C# (for free using Visual Studio and iText library), install it on end users computers and run whenever I need via VBA. Here are some links for more guidance:

1. How to develop pdf converter in C#: [link](https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/180443/Convert-a-PDF-File-to-Excel-File-using-iTextSharp-using-C-Net/)
2. How to create Excel Addin in C#: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-excel?view=vs-2019)
3. How to run C# addin from VBA: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-in-a-vsto-add-in-from-vba?view=vs-2019)

Overall it's fairly complicated but once done works like a dream.

Another solution as mentioned before is to use sendkeys in VBA. My experience is that it requires some optimization to handle various opening and copying times (depending on file size). Below is code that worked for me, however it's not even near that fast and stable as C# converter.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'Initialize sleep function via Windows API
Public Sub CopyToSheet(destinationSheet As Worksheet, pathToPdf as String)
'Copy data from PDF to worksheet

    'Initialize timer
    Dim StartTime As Double
    StartTime = Timer

    'Clear clipboard
    Dim myData As DataObject
    Set myData = New DataObject
    myData.SetText text:=Empty
    myData.PutInClipboard
    Set myData = Nothing

    'Build file paths
    Dim pathToAdobe As String
    pathToAdobe = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"""
    pathToPdf = """" & pathToPdf & """"

    'Open PDF and wait untill it is open. If file is already opened it will be just activated
    Dim pdfId As Long
    pdfId = Shell(pathToAdobe & " " & pathToPdf, vbMaximizedFocus)
    Do
        Sleep (500)
        If Round(Timer - StartTime, 2) > 9 Then MsgBox "Failed to open PDF": Exit Sub  'Safety check
    Loop Until Me.IsPdfOpen(pathToPdf)

    'Copy and wait until copying is completed
    SendKeys "^a"
    SendKeys "^c"
    Do
        Sleep (500)
        If Round(Timer - StartTime, 2) > 18 Then MsgBox "Failed to copy data to clipboard": Exit Sub  'Safety check
    Loop Until Me.GetClipboardStatus = "ClipboardHasData"

    'Paste data into worksheet
    destinationSheet.Activate
    destinationSheet.Range("A1").Select
    destinationSheet.Paste

    'Close pdf
    Call Shell("TaskKill /F /PID " & CStr(pdfId), vbHide)

    'Clear clipboard
    Set myData = New DataObject
    myData.SetText text:=Empty
    myData.PutInClipboard
    Set myData = Nothing

End Sub

Function IsPdfOpen(pathToPdf) As Boolean
'Check if PDF is already opened

    'Build window name (window name is name of the application on Windows task bar)
    Dim windowName As String
    windowName = pathToPdf
    windowName = Mid(windowName, InStrRev(windowName, "\") + 1, Len(windowName) - InStrRev(windowName, "\") + 1)
    windowName = windowName + " - Adobe Acrobat Reader DC"

    'Try to activate application to check if is opened
    On Error Resume Next
    AppActivate windowName, True
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 5: IsPdfOpen = False
        Case 0: IsPdfOpen = True
        Case Else: Debug.Assert False
    End Select
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Function GetClipboardStatus() As String
'Check if copying data to clipboard is completed

    Dim tempString As String
    Dim myData As DataObject

    'Try to put data from clipboard to string to check if operations on clipboard are completed
    On Error Resume Next
    Set myData = New DataObject
    myData.GetFromClipboard
    tempString = myData.GetText(1)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        If tempString = "" Then
            GetClipboardStatus = "ClipboardEmpty"
        Else
            GetClipboardStatus = "ClipboardHasData"
        End If
    Else
        GetClipboardStatus = "ClipboardBusy"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set myData = Nothing

End Function
```