# not able to copy data from PDF file

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook

I am able to open pdf doc from attachments from mail. Now I want to copy its content. kindly provide code to select all and copy. Below is the code and I have mentioned where I need help.
I am able to open pdf doc from attachments from mail. Now I want to copy its content. kindly provide code to select all and copy. Below is the code and I have mentioned where I need help.

```
Sub ExtractFirstUnreadEmailDetails()
    Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
    Dim oOlItm As Object
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
     'On Error Resume Next
    '~~> Outlook Variables for email

    Dim eSender As String, dtRecvd As String, dtSent As String
    Dim sSubj As String, sMsg As String
    Dim AttchType As String

    '~~> Get Outlook instance
    Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
    Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    '~~> Check if there are any actual unread emails 'apurv
    'If oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True").Count = 0 Then 'apurv
      '  MsgBox "NO Unread Email In Inbox" 'apurv
       ' Exit Sub 'apurv
   ' End If 'apurv

    '~~> Store the relevant info in the variables
    'For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
            For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items
                        eSender = oOlItm.SenderEmailAddress
                        dtRecvd = oOlItm.ReceivedTime
                        dtSent = oOlItm.CreationTime
                        sSubj = oOlItm.Subject
                        sMsg = oOlItm.Body
                        ToAddress = oOlItm.To

                    i = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

                         Range("c" & (i + 1)).Value = eSender
                         Range("B" & (i + 1)).Value = dtRecvd
                         'range("c"&(i+1)).Value=dtSent
                         Range("E" & (i + 1)).Value = sSubj
                         Range("F" & (i + 1)).Value = sMsg
                         Range("D" & (i + 1)).Value = ToAddress

                                If oOlItm.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
                                         temp = ""
                                         For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments
                                           temp = temp & "//" & oOlAtch.Filename
                                         Next
                                         Range("G" & (i + 1)).Value = temp
                                End If

                                If oOlItm.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
                                         temp = ""
                                         For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments
                                         If InStr(1, UCase(oOlAtch.Filename), "PDF", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then
                                         oOlAtch.SaveAsFile "D:\Users\apawar\Desktop\Attachments\" & oOlAtch.Filename
                                         Shell "Explorer.exe /e,D:\Users\apawar\Desktop\Attachments\" & oOlAtch.Filename, vbNormalFocus
                                         'NEED HELP HERE......Need to copy all data from pdf doc from 1st page
                                         End If
                                         Next
                                         Range("G" & (i + 1)).Value = temp
                                End If
            Next



MsgBox ("Down loaded successufully")
End Sub
```

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37287583/7889129

Answer (score -1):

You should probably get Acrobat, and this will be much easier.  Or, convert the PDF into a text file, simply by saving it, and import the text into Excel.