# How do I copy and paste data from pdf to excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Scenario: I have tons of Invoices received in my e-mail and saving them in a `folder("C:\Users\Vbattul2\Desktop\Invoices\")` and manually opening them one by one copying the needed data and pasting them to my excel tracker. Note that all the invoices have the same formats.

Opportunity to Automate: Automate the process of copy and paste of needed data from pdf and paste it to excel dummy worksheet(data delimited with colon & blank) and paste cell references in Excel invoice tracker.

Design: I will need to copy the pdf and paste it to a dummy worksheet then paste it to my excel invoice tracker.

I tried running this code from a thread posted 3 years ago:

[VBA Copying data from pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835164/vba-copying-data-from-pdf/37287583#37287583?newreg=17cbda959f594ea188ed3d98ae790c9c)

I couldn't seem to understand this line, so it is returning me an

```
error: 1004 Method 'Range' of object'_Global failed

Line Error: For Each fName In Range("path")
```

I also tried replacing the ("path") to my folder path where I save all the invoices but it doesn't work.

```
Sub StartAdobe1()
    Dim fName       As Variant
    Dim wbTransfer  As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wsNew       As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim dOpenCol    As Double
    Dim oPDFApp     As AcroApp
    Dim oAVDoc      As AcroAVDoc
    Dim oPDDoc      As AcroPDDoc
'Define your spreadsheet
Set wbTransfer = Workbooks("transfer.xlsm")
Set wsNew = wbTransfer.Sheets("new")
'Find first open column
dOpenCol = wsNew.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

'Instantiate Acrobat Objects
Set oPDFApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set oAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
Set oPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

For Each fName In Range("path")

'Open the PDF file. The AcroAVDoc.Open function returns a true/false
'to tell you if it worked
If oAVDoc.Open(fName.Text, "") = True Then
    Set oPDDoc = oAVDoc.GetPDDoc
Else
    Debug.Assert False
End If

'Copy all using Acrobat menu
oPDFApp.MenuItemExecute ("SelectAll")
oPDFApp.MenuItemExecute ("Copy")

'Paste into open column
wbTransfer.Activate
wsNew.Cells(1, dOpenCol).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Select next open column
dOpenCol = dOpenCol + 1

oAVDoc.Close (1)    '(1)=Do not save changes
oPDDoc.Close

Next
'Clean up
Set wbTransfer = Nothing
Set wsNew = Nothing
Set oPDFApp = Nothing
Set oAVDoc = Nothing
Set oPDDoc = Nothing


End Sub
```

i have uploaded an attachment where the actual result in dummy worksheet(paste as delimited values - colon & blank) should look like and the excel invoice tracker.

here are the links.

https://www.dropbox.com/preview/Marketing/desired%20output%20from%20pdf%20to%20excel.xlsm?role=work

https://www.dropbox.com/preview/Marketing/MRC%201380%20INVENTORY%202019.xlsb?role=work

Answer (score 0):

You would probably well served if you first convert all PDF files into text files, and import all data from all text files into Multiple sheets in Excel.

```
Sub convertpdf2()

Dim AcroXApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim AcroXAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim AcroXPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim Filename As String
Dim jsObj As Object
Dim NewFileName As String

Filename = "C:\your_path_here\test.pdf"
NewFileName = "C:\your_path_here\Desktop\test.txt"

Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
'AcroXApp.Show

Set AcroXAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
AcroXAVDoc.Open Filename, "Acrobat"

Set AcroXPDDoc = AcroXAVDoc.GetPDDoc
Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject
jsObj.SaveAs NewFileName, "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text"

AcroXAVDoc.Close False
AcroXApp.Hide
AcroXApp.Exit

End Sub
```

Or, put everything in all the text files into one single sheet in Excel, assuming all files have the same schema, of course.

Import several test files into separate sheets in Excel.

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
'updateby Extendoffice 20151015
    Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xTempWb As Workbook
    Dim xDelimiter As String
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xDelimiter = "|"
    xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", , "Kutools for Excel", , True)
    If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Kutools for Excel"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If
    I = 1
    Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
    xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    xTempWb.Close False
    xWb.Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    Do While I < UBound(xFilesToOpen)
        I = I + 1
        Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
        With xWb
            xTempWb.Sheets(1).Move after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=xDelimiter
        End With
    Loop
ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xTempWb = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "Kutools for Excel"
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

If you have Acrobat installed, you can try the script below.

```
Sub Convert_to_TXT()

Dim AcroXApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim AcroXAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim AcroXPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim Filename As String
Dim jsObj As Object
Dim NewFileName As String

    Const sPath = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\"
    Const sExt = ".pdf"
    Const dPath = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\"
    Const dExt = ".txt"

    Dim sName As String, dName As String, fCount As Long

    'loop through all files in source
    sName = Dir(sPath & "*" & sExt)

    Do While sName <> ""
        fCount = fCount + 1
            'we have sName. Now figure out dName
            dName = Left(sName, InStrRev(sName, ".") - 1) & dExt
            Set AcroXApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
            'AcroXApp.Show
            Set AcroXAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
            AcroXAVDoc.Open sName, "Acrobat"
            Set AcroXPDDoc = AcroXAVDoc.GetPDDoc
            Set jsObj = AcroXPDDoc.GetJSObject
            jsObj.SaveAs dName, "com.adobe.acrobat.plain-text"
        'find the next file
        sName = Dir
    Loop

AcroXAVDoc.Close False
AcroXApp.Hide
AcroXApp.Exit

    MsgBox "Found " & fCount & " files."
End Sub
```

If you do NOT have Acrobat installed, you can try the script below

```
Sub ConvertToTXT()
Dim file As Variant, wdDoc As Document
file = Dir("C:\your_path\" & "*.pdf") 'txt path
Do While (file <> "")
  Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\your_path\" & file, ReadOnly:=True, _
    AddToRecentFiles:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Visible:=False)
  wdDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\your_path\" & Replace(file, ".pdf", ".txt"), _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
  wdDoc.Close False
  file = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much asher for your support! appreciate it. the code works fine. can you also share how can I convert all files located in a folder? is it possible to disregard this NewFileName = "C:\your_path_here\Desktop\test.txt", and replace it with a code that saves the txt file automatically with the same filename as the invoice?

Comment: I just updated my last answer.  Please make the answer as useful if it helps you.  Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your help. I will try to work on it this week. Sorry I got so busy @ work for the past few weeks and got no time to open this site. I Apologize. I will update you once I am done working on this project. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sounds good.  If my answer helps you, please click 'this answer is useful'.  Thanks.

Comment: hi again. I got an error while running the updated codes you provided, the one with loop syntax. Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Answer (score 0):

So , what do you have now, all Excel files or all text files?

If all Excel files, try this.

```
Note: Copy all code below in a normal module of your workbook

#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
    "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
    "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long
#End If


Sub ChDirNet(szPath As String)
    SetCurrentDirectoryA szPath
End Sub

Sub Basic_Example_2()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String
    Dim FName As Variant


    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    SaveDriveDir = CurDir
    ChDirNet "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
                                        MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(FName) Then

        'Add a new workbook with one sheet
        Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
        rnum = 1


        'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
        For Fnum = LBound(FName) To UBound(FName)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(FName(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = FName(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
    ChDirNet SaveDriveDir
End Sub
```

If all text files, try this.

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
        lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, _
        ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal hProcess As Long, _
        lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#End If


Public Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400
Public Const STILL_ACTIVE = &H103


Public Sub ShellAndWait(ByVal PathName As String, Optional WindowState)
    Dim hProg As Long
    Dim hProcess As Long, ExitCode As Long
    'fill in the missing parameter and execute the program
    If IsMissing(WindowState) Then WindowState = 1
    hProg = Shell(PathName, WindowState)
    'hProg is a "process ID under Win32. To get the process handle:
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, hProg)
    Do
        'populate Exitcode variable
        GetExitCodeProcess hProcess, ExitCode
        DoEvents
    Loop While ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE
End Sub


Sub Merge_CSV_Files()
    Dim BatFileName As String
    Dim TXTFileName As String
    Dim XLSFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim DefPath As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oFolder
    Dim foldername

    'Create two temporary file names
    BatFileName = Environ("Temp") & _
            "\CollectCSVData" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy-h-mm-ss") & ".bat"
    TXTFileName = Environ("Temp") & _
            "\AllCSV" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy-h-mm-ss") & ".txt"

    'Folder where you want to save the Excel file
    DefPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        DefPath = DefPath & "\"
    End If

    'Set the extension and file format
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007 or higher
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        'If you want to save as xls(97-2003 format) in 2007 use
        'FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
    End If

    'Name of the Excel file with a date/time stamp
    XLSFileName = DefPath & "MasterCSV " & _
                  Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy h-mm-ss") & FileExtStr

    'Browse to the folder with CSV files
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oFolder = oApp.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder with CSV files", 512)
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        foldername = oFolder.Self.Path
        If Right(foldername, 1) <> "\" Then
            foldername = foldername & "\"
        End If

        'Create the bat file
        Open BatFileName For Output As #1
        Print #1, "Copy " & Chr(34) & foldername & "*.csv" _
                & Chr(34) & " " & TXTFileName
        Close #1

        'Run the Bat file to collect all data from the CSV files into a TXT file
        ShellAndWait BatFileName, 0
        If Dir(TXTFileName) = "" Then
            MsgBox "There are no csv files in this folder"
            Kill BatFileName
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Open the TXT file in Excel
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=TXTFileName, Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow _
                :=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
                Space:=False, Other:=False

        'Save text file as a Excel file
        Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Wb.SaveAs Filename:=XLSFileName, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Wb.Close savechanges:=False
        MsgBox "You find the Excel file here: " & vbNewLine & XLSFileName

        'Delete the bat and text file you temporary used
        Kill BatFileName
        Kill TXTFileName

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

See the link below for all details.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section3.htm

Also, consider using this very useful Excel AddIn.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

Comment: hello Asher. this works awesome! though what I am missing is the conversion of my pdf files (100+ files) to txt files saved in folder "C:\Users\Vbattul2\Desktop\invoices\". this is previous code you recently shared and it only convert one pdf file. Filename = "C:\your_path_here\test.pdf"
NewFileName = "C:\your_path_here\Desktop\test.txt". is there a way where it can convert one pdf is to one txt file? so lets say 100 pdf files = 100 txt files.