# How to open a PDF?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to use VBA in Word to open a PDF document, and eventually do some text manipulation.

I've the code below as a test, which does not error and appears to be opening the pdf.

When I try to insert the text of the pdf I just opened in Word, it pastes a box with a question mark inside. I'm not sure if I'm not opening the PDF correctly, or if the file is opening at all.

```vb
'Earlier code truncated for brevity
Dim FSOSubFolder As Object
Dim FSOFile As Object
Dim anotherString As String

For Each FSOSubFolder In FSOFolder.SubFolders
    LoopAllSubFolders FSOSubFolder
Next

For Each FSOFile In FSOFolder.Files
    
    ActiveDocument.Range.InsertAfter ("File Name: " & FSOFile.Name & vbNewLine) 'This part works
    Dim myWord As Word.Application, myDoc As Word.Document
    Set myWord = New Word.Application  
    Set myDoc = myWord.Documents.Open(FileName:=FSOFile.Path, ConfirmConversions:=False, Format:="PDF Files")
    myDoc.Activate
    Selection.WholeStory
    anotherString = Selection.Range.Text
    myDoc.Close
    ActiveDocument.Range.InsertAfter (anotherString) 'This pastes a box with a question mark inside

    Set FSOFile = Nothing
    Set FSOSubFolder = Nothing

Next
```

I don't have screenupdating or warnings suppressed, and I don't see a new Word document open up as well.

Comment: Are you running this code in Word or Excel?

Comment: Hello, I'm running this code in Word currently, although I suppose I could run it in Excel if I add the right reference.

Comment: "PDF Files" is not a vaild parameter for the Format argument of Open. I googled _WdOpenFormat enumeration_ and got this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdopenformat

Comment: Good catch. I am able to open the document, thanks

Comment: This is for Excel but the general idea should remain the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835164/copying-data-from-multiple-pdf-files). I personally would try and avoid the send keys solution and go with the api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as though you have some code written for Excel that you are trying to use in Word

```
    Dim myWord As Word.Application, myDoc As Word.Document
    Set myWord = New Word.Application  
    Set myDoc = myWord.Documents.Open(FileName:=FSOFile.Path, ConfirmConversions:=False, Format:="PDF Files")
    myDoc.Activate
```

As you are running the code in Word you already have an instance of Word so there is no need to open a new one, and you definitely don't want to create a new instance of Word for each file you attempt to open, especially as your code doesn't quit any of those extra instances. You are not seeing the documents being opened as your code does not make the additional instances of Word visible.

Your code with all the unnecessary bits removed:

```
   'Earlier code truncated for brevity
   Dim FSOSubFolder As Object
   Dim FSOFile As Object
   Dim anotherString As String

   For Each FSOSubFolder In FSOFolder.SubFolders
      LoopAllSubFolders FSOSubFolder
   Next
   
   Dim originalDoc As Word.Document
   Set originalDoc = ActiveDocument

   For Each FSOFile In FSOFolder.Files
    
      originalDoc.Range.InsertAfter ("File Name: " & FSOFile.Name & vbNewLine) 'This part works
      Dim pdfDoc As Word.Document
      Set pdfDoc = Documents.Open(filename:=FSOFile.Path, ConfirmConversions:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto)
      'use this if you just want the text content without formatting
      originalDoc.Range.InsertAfter pdfDoc.Content.Text
      'use this is if you want the formatted content
      'originalDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
      'originalDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.FormattedText = pdfDoc.Content.FormattedText
      pdfDoc.Close

      Set FSOFile = Nothing
      Set FSOSubFolder = Nothing
   Next
```

As you are attempting to open pdf's you will likely get the notification that Word will attempt to convert it despite setting `ConfirmConversions:=False`

Comment: Some pdfs do not edit in Word. They are simply pictures of text and need to be run through an OCR program.